# .htaccess to force remove file extension in address

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need an .htaccess file which will do something like this:

1. When user input `www.site.com/some_folder/test` it will keep the address as it is and open the corresponding page (test.php)
2. When user input `www.site.com/some_folder/test.php` it will remove .php extension to `www.site.com/some_folder/test` and it will open the corresponding page (test.php)

What I have right now is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and it can only fulfill first scenario but not the second. (when I input `www.site.com/some_folder/test.php` it will still show `www.site.com/some_folder/test.php`)

What should I change / add in the .htaccess file to fulfill 2nd scenario ?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Comment: so does the answer below works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following directives to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

Edit:
if you're in Localhost :

```
RewriteBase /sitename/
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: it's almost working.. however when I try it in my xampp it removes the 'sitename' so instead of `localhost/sitename/folder/test.php` it becomes `localhost/folder/test` any idea what is missing ? or it is not supposed to be tested on xampp ? thanks before.

Comment: because you're in localhost, the root in your case is www not sitename, I've updated my answer ,should work if your .htaccess is in /sitename/